# State management techniques ASP .NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and have worked in ASP.NET before. I am starting a new project in ASP.NET MVC 2 and wanted to find out what all state management techniques are available in ASP.NET MVC 2.

Can anyone please suggest some good resource.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Session` just as in ASP.NET WebForms. Was there anything else you wondered? You don't have ViewState as in WebForms, but you can use `ViewData`to pass data between controllers and views (see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx). What kind of state are you planning to manage?

Answer (score 0):

For state management you can use `Session`, but to do it the MVC way, you should combine it with action filters.

Here are some links that can help you:

- [ASP.NET MVC Filters and Statefulness](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/aspnet-mvc-filters-and-statefulness.html)
- [mvcConf 2 - Brad Wilson: Advanced MVC 3](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2011-Brad-Wilson-Advanced-MVC-3)